# LazyList loaded image much smaller than original

Tags: android-listview, android-image, lazylist

I just copy the sample of listview to my code,and i found that the image i download from url and show in my adt is so mall,much smaller than it should be.
I want to show get the original image from the url, how should i do? please help.